# Same Latex source file but receive different result after compiling

Tags: debugging

I'm using Latex to typeset a big file, which i need to include 2 sub-files

> \input{titres/remerciements.tex}
> \input{titres/resume.tex}

The 2 files are in French and there is already the declaration of language package in the big file

> \usepackage[francais, english]{babel}

When I tried to compiled the 2 sub-files (using TexStudio), what I received is very incomprehensible: 2 different fonts even when the source code of each sub-file is the same at 100%.

This is the result of the first sub-file

> [image]

And this is the result of the second sub-file (which is the result I want) with the source code identical at 100%

> [image]

What I want is to make the first sub-file provides the true result as in the second sub-file. Could you please show me how to do it ? Thank you very much!!

Comment: the accented A tells you that the included file is UTF-8 encoded but is being treated as latin-1 either because you have a very old latex or you have specified that with `\usepackage[latin1][inputenc}` or similar I would guess?

Comment: please always provide an example _as text_ it is impossible to debug an image of code, especially when the image doesn't show the releavant lines setting the encoding

Comment: so you could use your editor to save the first sub file as latin-1 (iso-8859-1) encoding, but better would be to save all your files as UTF-8 (which has been the default encoding in latex for the last few releases)